# find() with multiple substrings - Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

How would I find the first occurrence of either the character `e` or `o`?

I want to do something like this:

```
my_string = "Hello World"
x = my_string.find('e' or 'o',my_string)
print x # 1
```

Comment: its not clear, you want 1st occurance of both e or o, OR you want only any one??

Comment: It's fairly clear. The first sentence literally reads "How would I find the first occurrence of either the character `e` or `o`?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function with a generator expression, like this

```
>>> next(idx for idx, char in enumerate("Hello World") if char in 'eo')
1
```

It will give the index of the first character which is either `e` or `o`.

**Note:** It will fail if the characters are not there in the string. So, you can optionally pass the default value, like this

```
>>> next((idx for idx, char in enumerate("Hello World") if char in 'eo'), None)
1
>>> next((idx for idx, char in enumerate("Hi") if char in 'eo'), None)
None
```

Comment: What's the use of `next` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The argument passed to `enumerate` is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). It is like a normal function, but it can return values whenever you ask for the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.next) value from it, till it exhausts.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do a `find` on each character and then take the minimum of all the results (throwing away the `-1`s unless all of them are `-1`):

```
def first_index(string, search_chars):

    finds = [string.find(c) for c in search_chars]
    finds = [x for x in finds if x >= 0]

    if finds:
        return min(finds)
    else:
        return -1
```

This yields:

```
>>> first_index("Hello World", "eo")
1
>>> first_index("Hello World", "xyz")
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> my_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,x in enumerate("hello world"):
...     if x in "eo":
...         my_dict[x].append(i)
... 
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'e': [1], 'o': [4, 7]})
>>> my_dict['e'][0]     # 1st  'e'
1
>>> my_dict['o'][0]     # 1st 'o'
4
```